# Does changing code on Heroku require some kind of restart and if so how

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I made a test app on Heroku to try to upload using the CarrierWave gem and Amazon S3

I successfully uploaded a picture onto Heroku from a form on my test app. However, when I look in my Amazon console, it says the bucket (there's only one bucket right now) is empty, and I discovered that it didn't actually go to Amazon, because I had the storage set as

```
storage :file
```

in my images_uploader file. When I changed it to

```
storage :fog
```

and pushed the code to heroku again, the application broke. How can that break an application? Is there some kind of restart to the server I have to do on heroku (anyting besides git push heroku master)

```
2012-01-15T02:27:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:27:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:27:20+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:27:20+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:28:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:28:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:28:42+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-15T02:28:42+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET s3carry.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Pushing to Heroku restarts your app. Were you able to run your app on your local machine in production mode and make requests? There will be more debugging information in the log (stack trace).

Comment: no, I didn't try (stupid me). I tried now and got an error message 'unknown region Oregon' in UsersControler#create action...I don't understand this because the region is set in the initializer.

Comment: got it to work, no worries. just took out the region from the config

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a gem 'fog' installed.